# Python dataclass inheritance with mutable default arguments returns zero-value

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance, python-dataclasses

I am trying to calculate a radius-like quantity from 3 lists containing Cartesian coordinates x, y & z.
Below is my minimal code example to reproduce the issue I am facing;
The child-class calculates the radius-quantity but returns a zero-value.
What is the reason for this, and how can it be fixed?

Script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import List


@dataclass
class LoadHalo:
    x: List = field(default_factory=list)
    y: List = field(default_factory=list)
    z: List = field(default_factory=list)

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.x = [1, 2, 3]
        self.y = [1, 3, 5]
        self.z = [1, 4, 7]


@dataclass
class BinHalo(LoadHalo):
    r: List = field(default_factory=list)

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.r = self.modulus(self.x, self.y, self.z)

    def modulus(self, *args):
        """Modulus of vector of arbitrary size."""
        return sum([i ** 2 for containers in args for i in containers]) ** .5


halo = BinHalo()
print(f"halo.x: {halo.x}")
print(f"halo.r: {halo.r}")
```

Which outputs the following values for x and r:

```
halo.x: []
halo.r: 0.0
```

Comment: add `super().__post_init__()` before `self.r = self.modulus(self.x, self.y, self.z)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are *overriding* `__post_init__`, so the lists are still empty because they never got initialized with anything other than the empty list default. You must call the super-class method that you are overriding if you want its behavior as well.

What you want is the following:

```
def __post_init__(self):
    super().__post_init__()
    self.r = self.modulus(self.x, self.y, self.z)
```

Note a couple of things with your type-hints: you probably wanted `float` for the `r` field in the subclass, and also for the return type of `modulus`:

```
def modulus(self, *args) -> float:
    ...
```

also, you should initialize the default lists with `float` objects so you can write:

```
x: List[float]
```

For your list fields, since presumably you want to use floating point math.

So all-in all, I'd define everything like:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import List


@dataclass
class LoadHalo:
    x: List[float] = field(default_factory=list)
    y: List[float] = field(default_factory=list)
    z: List[float] = field(default_factory=list)

    def __post_init__(self) -> None:
        self.x = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
        self.y = [1.0, 3.0, 5.0]
        self.z = [1.0, 4.0, 7.0]


@dataclass
class BinHalo(LoadHalo):
    r: float = 0.0 # or whatever is suitable

    def __post_init__(self) -> None:
        super().__post_init__()
        self.r = self.modulus(self.x, self.y, self.z)

    def modulus(self, *args: List[float]) -> float:
        """Modulus of vector of arbitrary size."""
        return sum([i ** 2 for containers in args for i in containers]) ** .5
```

Comment: Very clear working example. Just what I was looking for. Thank you @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: @GustavRasmussen no worries, you should consider using `mypy` to type-check your code.